# How should I write Pagination component React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pagination

I am building a web-app and I am also new with web-dev and all. I have backend-response as json with pagination in it, looks like that:

```
{
    "count": 16,
    "next": "http://localhost:8000/en/api/events/?page=3",
    "previous": "http://localhost:8000/en/api/events/",
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "",
            "id": ,
            "title": "",
            "creation_date": "",
            "description": "",
            "event_date": "",
            "link": ""
        },
        ...
    ],
    "total_pages": 4
}
```

And I want to add pagination to my EventList.jsx component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Content.css";
import "./Pagination";

import { useLanguage } from "../../context/LanguageTranslator";
import { getLanguage } from "../../utils/getLanguage";
import Pagination from "./Pagination";

const initialState = {
  fullAPI: {
    count: 0,
    next: null,
    previous: null,
    results: [],
    total_pages: 0,
  },
};


const EventList = (props) => {
  const { language } = useLanguage();
  const currentLanguage = getLanguage(language);

  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const langUrl = currentLanguage.urlName;
      const page = props.match.params.page;
      const defaultUrl = `http://localhost:8000/${langUrl}/api/events/?page=${page}`;
      // * url which we will fetch
      let currentUrl;

      currentUrl = defaultUrl;

      const res = await fetch(currentUrl);
      const fullAPI = await res.json();

      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, fullAPI }));
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(error);
    }
  }, []);

  const renderEvents = () => {
    const eventsList = state.fullAPI.results;

    return eventsList.map((item) => (
      <li key={item.id}>
        <p>
          {currentLanguage.title}:{item.title}
        </p>
        <p>
          <a href={item.link} className="aa">
            {currentLanguage.organizers}
          </a>
        </p>
        <Link to={`/events/id=${item.id}`} className="aa">
          {currentLanguage.linkToEvent}
        </Link>
      </li>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <div>
        <ul>{renderEvents()}</ul>
        <Pagination
          totalPages={state.fullAPI.total_pages}
          next={state.fullAPI.next}
          previous={state.fullAPI.previous}
          currentPage={props.page}
        />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
};

export default EventList;
```

Basically now I have this Pagination.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link, NavLink, Redirect, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Content.css";
import "./pagination.css";

const Pagination = (props) => {
  // * pagination

  const pages = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= props.totalPages; ++i) {
    pages.push(i);
  }

  const handleClick = (number) => {
    return `/events/page=${number}`;
  };

  const renderPageNumbers = pages.map((number) => {
    return (
      <li
        key={number}
        id={number}
        onClick={() => {
          window.location.href = handleClick(number);
        }}
      >
        {number}
      </li>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {props.currentPage}
      <ul className="pageNumbers">{renderPageNumbers}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

A coded it this way because I needed to reload page in order to fetch a response from server. So now I reload page and have no ability to store state inside the Pagination component and can't do things like this:
[frist] [prev] 1 [2] ... 9 10 [next] [last]

only this:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not *only* fetch a response from the server on page load. You can initially fetch on page load, but loading from the server should be in a separate function that's *both* called from within `useEffect` as well as when the user wants to go to the next or previous page.

As for the [first] [prev] kind of thing, you'll need to add separate elements for that. You're currently creating an array of every page--instead you probably just want to have individual elements for `[first]` `[prev]`, `[n-2]` through `[n+2]`, `[next]`, and `[last]`. I notice your response has `next` and `previous` links, but, if possible, you're probably better off just sending the current page and then fetching the previous or next page number yourself (since you already know the endpoint to hit).

Anyway, I did my best, it didn't seem like you gave a specific question so I tried to answer what it looks like you were having trouble with.

Comment: I didn’t really get the fetch part, could you please give an example, if possible? 
In general  I wanted to know, whether I’m  doing the right thing with page reloading or is there a way to navigate through pages by Link tags or any other way (without reloading). 
Because now I rewrote it, removed onClick method, added <Link to={`/events/page=${number}`}\> and it changes url but not renders the page.

Comment: In the array of your `useEffect()` (which is currently just `[]`), put in the page number so that it's `[props.match.params.page]`. Your `useEffect()` will re-execute every time that prop changes, and therefore when the page changes, you'll fetch the data again.